# Java thread issues with pause and resume via button

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm learning about threads and trying to adapt this [tutorial](http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/c12/ex5-ans.html) and this [tutorial](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0160__Thread/Suspendresumeandstopathread.htm).

Something's not right, though, as the thread doesn't continue past one iteration of the for loop and the actionListener implementation for the button isn't working.

**Originally, I got the thread working in this way :**

```
private class EstiPi implements Runnable {

    final int numDisplay = 5000000;
    long numEstimation;
    long numTouchCircle;
    public volatile boolean timeToQuit = false;
    private EstiPiGui gui;
    double estiPi;

    public EstiPi() {
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Thread started");
        while (!timeToQuit) {
            for (int i = 0; i < numDisplay; i++) {
                double x = Math.random();
                double y = Math.random();
                numEstimation++;
                if (x * x + y * y < 1) {
                    numTouchCircle++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(numEstimation);
            System.out.println(numTouchCircle);
            estiPi = ((double) numTouchCircle / numEstimation) * 4;
            estiPiLabel.setText(String.valueOf(estiPi));
        }
    }
}
```

**But now i'm trying to add GUI to pause and resume**

My runnable class to integrate button control :

```
private class EstiPi implements Runnable {

    final int numDisplay = 5000000;
    long numEstimation;
    long numTouchCircle;
    double estiPi;

    public EstiPi() {
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Thread started");
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < numDisplay; i++) {
                double x = Math.random();
                double y = Math.random();
                numEstimation++;
                if (x * x + y * y < 1) {
                    numTouchCircle++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(numEstimation);
            System.out.println(numTouchCircle);
            estiPi = ((double) numTouchCircle / numEstimation) * 4;
            estiPiLabel.setText(String.valueOf(estiPi));
            synchronized (this) {
                while (!running) {
                    wait();
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted");
        }
    }

}
```

Button action performed this way :

```
private void runPauseButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if (running) {
        runPauseButton.setText("Run");
        running = false;

    } else {
        runPauseButton.setText("Pause");
        synchronized (piThread) {
            running = true;
            piThread.notify();
        }
    }
}
```

Starting thread when initiating gui components:

```
public EstiPiGui() {
    initComponents();
    piRunner = new EstiPi();
    piThread = new Thread(piRunner);
    add(estiPiLabel);
    add(estiCountLabel);
    piThread.start();

}
```

My buttons and labels:

```
private javax.swing.JLabel estiCountLabel;
private javax.swing.JLabel estiPiLabel;
private javax.swing.JButton runPauseButton;
```

**UPDATE**
After integrating an SO user's answer and adding a while (true) block, pressing the button labeled "Run" changes the labels. Pressing pause, however, doesn't do anything.

Strangely, the print statement after mLock.wait() outputs even if I don't press the pause button. *Is the running variable becoming false somewhere that I am not seeing?*

```
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Thread started");
        while (true) {
            for (int i = 0; i < numDisplay; i++) {
                try {
                    synchronized (mLock) {
                        while (!running) {
                            mLock.wait();
                            System.out.println("mLock : waiting");
                            System.out.println(running);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
                double x = Math.random();
                double y = Math.random();
                numEstimation++;
                if (x * x + y * y < 1) {
                    numTouchCircle++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(numEstimation);
            System.out.println(numTouchCircle);
            estiPi = ((double) numTouchCircle / numEstimation) * 4;
            estiPiLabel.setText(String.valueOf(estiPi));
        }
    }
```

The button action and initializing variables:

```
public class EstiPiGui extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    static EstiPiGui myGui;
    public volatile boolean running;
    EstiPi piRunner;
    Thread piThread;
    public static final Object mLock = new Object();

    /**
     * Creates new form EstPiGui
     */
    public EstiPiGui() {
        initComponents();
        piRunner = new EstiPi();
        piThread = new Thread(piRunner);
        add(estiPiLabel);
        add(estiCountLabel);
        piThread.start();

    }

    private void runPauseButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        if (running) {
            runPauseButton.setText("Run");
            synchronized (mLock) {
            running = false;
            }

        }
        if (!running) {
            runPauseButton.setText("Pause");
            synchronized (mLock) {
                running = true;
                mLock.notify();
            }
        }
    }                                              

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                myGui = new EstiPiGui();
                myGui.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

    }

    private class EstiPi implements Runnable {

        final int numDisplay = 5000000;
        long numEstimation;
        long numTouchCircle;
        //public volatile boolean running;
        private EstiPiGui gui;
        double estiPi;

        public EstiPi() {
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Thread started");
            while (true) {
                for (int i = 0; i < numDisplay; i++) {
                    try {
                        synchronized (mLock) {
                            while (!running) {
                                mLock.wait();
                                System.out.println("mLock : waiting");
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                    double x = Math.random();
                    double y = Math.random();
                    numEstimation++;
                    if (x * x + y * y < 1) {
                        numTouchCircle++;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(numEstimation);
                System.out.println(numTouchCircle);
                estiPi = ((double) numTouchCircle / numEstimation) * 4;
                estiPiLabel.setText(String.valueOf(estiPi));
                estiCountLabel.setText(String.valueOf(numEstimation));
            }
        }
    }


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel estiCountLabel;
    private javax.swing.JLabel estiPiLabel;
    private javax.swing.JButton runPauseButton;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Why does your question have two different versions of `EstiPi` class? Which version are you using?

Comment: @Chris The first one shows the version that was working, but does not integrate the button. The second is my attempt to integrate a button that does not work.

Comment: At first glance I can see a few problems: (1) You are calling `wait` on your `Runnable` class, and calling `notify` on your `Thread` (a different object, so the notify essentially has no effect). (2) Your pause/resume logic is outside of the work loop (so it won't actually pause anything other than your thread exiting).

Comment: @chris I see what you mean about calling wait and notify on different objects. Is there any way to avoid that? I passed the runnable object to a thread as I taught to--i'm learning though, so am open to suggestions.

Comment: The `mLock` alternative suggested in the below answer is probably the simplest alternative. It's just a shared object between the different threads for doing synchronization/wait/notify on. The key is that it's the _same_ object on both threads.

Comment: Your `running = false;` is not guaranteed to be seen by the waiting thread by the Java Memory Model. To ensure that it can be seen, either put that inside ` synchronized` block too, or make `running` a `volatile` variable (which it may already be - I don't see any declaration for your variable `running`)

Comment: Also, don't call any Swing methods like `estiPiLabel.setText(String.valueOf(estiPi));` from your Runnable. Swing is a single-threaded UI and you can really screw things up if you invoke methods on Swing components from other threads than the Swing thread. Use `EventQueue.invokeLater` if you want to do something in Swing from another thread.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt running is already volatile. I added the code where it was initialized.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I think the EvenQueue.invokeLater is already implemented as well. Honestly, it was generated by Netbeans--so i'm just now reading into it and realizing what it does. I added the code, feel free to let me know if you meant otherwise.

Comment: `The print statement after mLock.wait() outputs even if I don't press the pause button`. Java cannot guarantee that your worker thread wake-up due to `notify()` only. So you may see it prints output after `wait()`. That is why you need to place it in loop that check condition. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28long%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move following code block

```
synchronized (this) {
      while (!running) {
         wait();
      }
}
```

into `for` loop block.

```
       for (int i = 0; i < numDisplay; i++) {
            try {
              synchronized (mLock) {
                while (!running) {
                  mLock.wait();
                }
              }
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {           
               //do nothing just continue
            }

            double x = Math.random();
            double y = Math.random();
            numEstimation++;
            if (x * x + y * y < 1) {
                numTouchCircle++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(numEstimation);
        System.out.println(numTouchCircle);
        estiPi = ((double) numTouchCircle / numEstimation) * 4;
        estiPiLabel.setText(String.valueOf(estiPi));
```

**Update**

As pointed by Chris, lock need to be performed using same reference.

In your resume button click, change it to something like this.

```
if (!running) {
    synchronized (mLock) {
        running = true;
        mLock.notify();
    }
}
```

and `mLock` is a global object that can be access from piThread or main thread.

```
public static final Object mLock = new Object();
```

**Update**

You Run/Pause button does not work because your `if` condition check. When `running` is true then execution will enter first `if` and set `running` to false. Now `running == false`. Execution continues and when it's about to execute second `if`, `running = false` so condition `(!running)` returns true so it enters second `if` and set `running` back to true and call `mLock.notify()`, thus worker thread never pauses.

```
    if (running) {
        runPauseButton.setText("Run");
        synchronized (mLock) {
           running = false;
        }

    }
    if (!running) {
        runPauseButton.setText("Pause");
        synchronized (mLock) {
            running = true;
            mLock.notify();
        }
    }
```

Change it to `if .. else` block

```
    if (running) {
        runPauseButton.setText("Run");
        synchronized (mLock) {
           running = false;
        }
    } else {
        runPauseButton.setText("Pause");
        synchronized (mLock) {
            running = true;
            mLock.notify();
        }
    }
```

Comment: There's more to fix.. This by itself won't solve anything - see my comments on the main question above

Comment: Chris is correct. Object monitor locks need to be performed a single reference of the same lock.

Comment: See my latest comment on the question - nothing special about it other than its the same object in both places (as opposed to two different objects). Read up on synchronization/wait/notify for more details

Comment: By "only two iterations" do you mean your for loop is only doing 2 iterations instead of `numDisplay` iterations? I can't see anything in your code to cause that...

Comment: @Chris So sorry, my mistake -- I just erased the comment. See updates.

Comment: @ZamronyP.Juhara See edits. Starting the thread works, but pausing it doesn't seem to. Any ideas?